# How remove or skip spaces in nested loop patterns

Tags: java

I have this little code that is to create the output below:

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     # <- Wanted output


   ##
   ###
   ####
   #####
   ######
   ####### <- Current output
```

How do I add spaces and remove "#"? The pattern is six long (straight down) increasing by one each line but only having two "#" per line all the way down.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int BASE_SIZE = 6;

        for (int r = 0; r < BASE_SIZE; r++){

            for (int c = 0; c < (r+2); c++){
            System.out.print("#");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print one hash mark, print spaces up to current `r` value, then print final hash mark.

```
final int BASE_SIZE = 6;

for (int r = 0; r < BASE_SIZE; r++){
    System.out.print("#");
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("#");
}
```

prints

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
```

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly and you can specify the side size.

```java
public static void wantedPatern (int side) {
    for (int i = 0; i < side; i++){
        System.out.print("#");
        for(int k = -i; k < 0; k++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("#");
    }
}
```

Output with side 9 `wantedPatern(9)`

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
#      #
#       #
#        #
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to update your inner for loop where you print empty spaces if the column value is not first(c=0) and last ( c=r+1) for each row.

```
public class Pattern {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int BASE_SIZE = 6;

        for (int r = 0; r < BASE_SIZE; r++){

            for (int c = 0; c < (r+2); c++){
                if ( c == 0 || c == r+1)
            System.out.print("#");
                else 
                    System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

and the output is like this:

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
```